# How can I remove the white-space around the numbers on a JS timer?

Tags: css

I have a JavaScript timer here, and I am trying to remove the white-space around the numbers so that the entire timer is green.

I have tried using CSS to remove the white-space but have had no luck. I am unsure whether CSS or JS has to be used to remove the space.

This is the code for the timer

An image can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iQqmBA10FqOze5N6a8RiqikXBlidHHFf)

I just want to remove the white-space around the numbers. Thanks

```js
var flagclock = 0;
var flagstop = 1;
var stoptime = 0;
var currenttime;
var splitdate = '';
var output;
var clock;
var thetable = document.getElementById("timerTable");
// Adjust limits and colors here
// Specify limits in seconds
var limit1 = 0;
color1 = "lightgreen";
var limit2 = 360;
color2 = "orange";
var limit3 = 600;
color3 = "red";

function startstop() {
  var startdate = new Date();
  var starttime = startdate.getTime();
  if (flagclock == 0) {
    startstop.value = 'Stop';
    flagclock = 1;
    counter(starttime);
  } else {
    startstop.value = 'Start';
    flagclock = 0;
    flagstop = 1;
    splitdate = '';
  }
}

function counter(starttime) {
  output = document.getElementById('output');
  clock = document.getElementById('clock');
  currenttime = new Date();
  var timediff = currenttime.getTime() - starttime;
  if (flagstop == 1) {
    timediff = timediff + stoptime
  }
  if (flagclock == 1) {
    clock.value = formattime(timediff, '');
    refresh = setTimeout('counter(' + starttime + ');', 100);
    var secs = timediff / 1000;
    var thecolor = "white";
    if (secs > limit3) thecolor = color3;
    else if (secs > limit2) thecolor = color2;
    else if (secs > limit1) thecolor = color1;
    thetable.style.backgroundColor = thecolor;
    console.log(timediff / 1000)
  } else {
    window.clearTimeout(refresh);
    stoptime = timediff;
  }
}

function formattime(rawtime, roundtype) {
  if (roundtype == 'round') {
    var ds = Math.round(rawtime / 100) + '';
  } else {
    var ds = Math.floor(rawtime / 100) + '';
  }
  var sec = Math.floor(rawtime / 1000);
  var min = Math.floor(rawtime / 60000);
  ds = ds.charAt(ds.length - 1);
  if (min >= 15) {
    startstop();
  }
  sec = sec - 60 * min + '';
  if (sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) != '') {
    sec = sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
  } else {
    sec = 0 + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
  }
  min = min + '';
  if (min.charAt(min.length - 2) != '') {
    min = min.charAt(min.length - 2) + min.charAt(min.length - 1);
  } else {
    min = 0 + min.charAt(min.length - 1);
  }
  return min + ':' + sec;
}
```

```html
<body onload="startstop();">
  <table id="timerTable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="timerArea" id="clock" type="text" value="00:00" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;font-size:14pt;" readonly><br>
      </td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the entire timer green, you can set the CSS property [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) of the `<input>` element to "transparent". I've also removed the element's default border.

```css
.timerArea {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14pt;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

Here's a demonstration:

```js
var flagclock = 0;
var flagstop = 1;
var stoptime = 0;
var currenttime;
var splitdate = '';
var output;
var clock;
var thetable = document.getElementById("timerTable");
// Adjust limits and colors here
// Specify limits in seconds
var limit1 = 0;
color1 = "lightgreen";
var limit2 = 360;
color2 = "orange";
var limit3 = 600;
color3 = "red";

function startstop() {
  var startdate = new Date();
  var starttime = startdate.getTime();
  if (flagclock == 0) {
    startstop.value = 'Stop';
    flagclock = 1;
    counter(starttime);
  } else {
    startstop.value = 'Start';
    flagclock = 0;
    flagstop = 1;
    splitdate = '';
  }
}

function counter(starttime) {
  output = document.getElementById('output');
  clock = document.getElementById('clock');
  currenttime = new Date();
  var timediff = currenttime.getTime() - starttime;
  if (flagstop == 1) {
    timediff = timediff + stoptime
  }
  if (flagclock == 1) {
    clock.value = formattime(timediff, '');
    refresh = setTimeout('counter(' + starttime + ');', 100);
    var secs = timediff / 1000;
    var thecolor = "white";
    if (secs > limit3) thecolor = color3;
    else if (secs > limit2) thecolor = color2;
    else if (secs > limit1) thecolor = color1;
    thetable.style.backgroundColor = thecolor;
    console.log(timediff / 1000)
  } else {
    window.clearTimeout(refresh);
    stoptime = timediff;
  }
}

function formattime(rawtime, roundtype) {
  if (roundtype == 'round') {
    var ds = Math.round(rawtime / 100) + '';
  } else {
    var ds = Math.floor(rawtime / 100) + '';
  }
  var sec = Math.floor(rawtime / 1000);
  var min = Math.floor(rawtime / 60000);
  ds = ds.charAt(ds.length - 1);
  if (min >= 15) {
    startstop();
  }
  sec = sec - 60 * min + '';
  if (sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) != '') {
    sec = sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
  } else {
    sec = 0 + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
  }
  min = min + '';
  if (min.charAt(min.length - 2) != '') {
    min = min.charAt(min.length - 2) + min.charAt(min.length - 1);
  } else {
    min = 0 + min.charAt(min.length - 1);
  }
  return min + ':' + sec;
}

startstop();
```

```css
.timerArea {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14pt;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="timerTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="timerArea" id="clock" type="text" value="00:00" readonly><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```